# how to get fancybox from http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ to work with dynamic images comes from database

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using fancybox control from http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/. when I use a static image it works fine but when I bind the source to dynamic image come from database using http handler. it dosn't work and opens the image in a new page.

my html bind expression:

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" runat="server" href='<%# "Handler3.ashx?ID="+ Eval("ID") %>' title="Test">
<img src='<%# "Handler3.ashx?ID="+ Eval("ID") %>' runat="server" alt="Test" Height="500" Width="400" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you use static images, fancybox can identify the `type` of content (due to the image extension) but when you use dynamic images from a database, the rendered links may look like

```
<a href="Handler3.ashx?ID=7049" class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" title="Test">.....
```

...so fancybox has no means to know that the content is an `image` ... so you have to tell it inside your custom script like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({"type": "image"});
});
```